# jQuery Validate plugin not validating an element that's not a form input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I need to validate with jQuery Validation Plugin a combobox component: `jqxComboBox`. This component is applied on a `div`. So defining

```
<div id="component_id" />

$( "#component_id" ).jqxComboBox({...});

$("#component_id" ).rules( "add", {
    required: true,                  
    messages:{
        required: "Field is required"
    }
});
```

throws the following exception: `Cannot read property 'nodeType' of undefined`. I think it should due to the fact that I'm applying validation rules on a div.

This component generate an input type hidden to hold selected value. I have also tryed to apply validation rules on that hidden component, but this do not works: form is submitted also when hidden has no value.

```
$('input[type=hidden][name=myName]').rules( "add", {
    required: true,                  
    messages:{
        required: "Field is required"
    }
});
```

Can someone please give me some hints on how to solve this?

Comment: can you create a fiddle showing the issue? or at least provide the HTML code generated of the form and the div?

Comment: ..not now, I'm not at work. I can post it tomorrow! But this is the demonstration page of the component if can be useful! http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxcombobox/index.htm#demos/jqxcombobox/bindingtojson.htm

Comment: try to use only the name of the input field instead of using type as well. and check your generated final code to make sure you are targeting the right input element. ( e.g. you can even target it by ID if it has one )

Comment: @Ramy It doesn't have an id.. I have also tryed to omit type attribute. I think that the solution is in the answer below..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quote OP:**

*"I need to validate with jQuery Validation Plugin a combobox component: jqxComboBox. This component is applied on a div."*

As you learned, you cannot use jQuery Validate to validate a `div`.  You can only validate `input`, `select` and `textarea` elements that are within a `<form>` container.

**Quote OP:**

*"This component generate an input type hidden to hold selected value. I have also tryed to apply validation rules on that hidden component, but this do not works: form is submitted also when hidden has no value."*

Putting the value inside a hidden input element is an acceptable workaround.

However, by default, the jQuery Validate plugin will ignore all hidden input elements.  Simply change the `ignore` option to `[]` in order to ignore "nothing".  Set the `ignore` option inside your `.validate()` call along with any/all of your other options.

```
$('#yourform').validate({
    // your other options, rules and callbacks,
    ignore: []  // <- ignore nothing - validate hidden elements
});
```

**Documentation**:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#ignore

Comment: jQuery Validate plugin will ignore all hidden input elements: and it is a very convenient behaviour :) It could be a problem to me disable that behaviour only for make these combobox validation working.. anyway thank you for your answer, it is very useful

Comment: @gipinani, you don't have to disable it for everything.  Just replace `[]` with the appropriate jQuery selector, so that it ignores everything _except_ the one you want.

Comment: Can I specify that option directly on the field (better for me), or have I to set it to the form?

Comment: @gipinani, the `ignore` option is for "ignoring fields".